# Detach is undefined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to detach a `many-to-many` relationship in my *Laravel* application. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()
```

I have 2 models - `User` and `Item`. Each `User` can have many `Item`, but it needs to be in a custom table, `user_haves`.

*Item:*

```
public function usersHave() {
    return $this->hasMany('User', 'id', 'user_haves');
}
```

*User:*

```
public function haves() {
    return $this->hasMany('Item', 'id', 'users_have');
}
```

Now I am trying to detach it by doing the following:

```
Sentry::getUser()->haves()->detach($item->id);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you need to use `belongsToMany` instead of `hasMany`, for example:

```
public function usersHave() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_have');
}

public function haves() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Item', 'user_have');
}
```

Also need to create the `user_have` pivot table. [Check the manual](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many).